# Scalability of Sub Queries, and Possible Alternatives

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

Two things up front. First off I have a solution to my problem. I am here for guidance as to if it is a good solution and if I can make it better. Secondly I want to apologize for my ignorance up front! I am a java guy building a site who is just now getting into SQL. I still have a lot of learning to do which is why I'm here looking for guidance.

I have three tables that deal with this query.

1. Users - Basic information about all users on the site
2. Friends - Holds the user id's of two people who are friends
3. Strides - Think of strides like facebook wall posts. Any user can post a stride update on their wall or a friends wall.

The SQL statement for finding all of a users friends and returning their id number looks like this.

```
SELECT user.id 
FROM user 
INNER JOIN friends ON user.id = friends.user2 WHERE friends.user1 = 1 
UNION ALL 
SELECT user.id FROM user 
INNER JOIN friends on user.id = friends.user1 WHERE friends.user2 = 1
```

Now my goal is to have a facebook like live feed. So that any time a user posts a stride all of their friends are informed. So I knew step one was to get all of a users friends which I did so above. So now I want to link these friends to the stride table.

In the stride table there are columns for sourceUserId (the person who wrote the stride) and recipientId (the person who recieved the stride). So if your write on your own board and your id is 2 it would be a 2 for both columns. My goal is to create an SQL statment that can find all of a users friends, and all of the posts those friends have made on their board AND on their friends board.

After way too much googling I found out about SQL sub queries and have come up with a result. The problem is I am new and don't know if this is a good result since I just learned about these things today! I'm scared about scalability and if this thing will go haywire once I have 100, 1,000 or even 100,000 users! So my questions are,

1. Is a subquery the best option here? If so did I do it correctly? If not how can I fix this
2. Are there any columns I should index to speed up this query.
3. Do you have any other advice for a new SQL guy on how to improve my future queries

Here is the code I came up with!

```
SELECT * FROM stride WHERE sourceUserId = ANY
(
    SELECT user.id 
    FROM user 
    INNER JOIN friends ON user.id = friends.user2 WHERE friends.user1 = 1 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT user.id FROM user 
    INNER JOIN friends on user.id = friends.user1 WHERE friends.user2 = 1
) 
AND recipientId = ANY
(
    SELECT user.id 
    FROM user 
    INNER JOIN friends ON user.id = friends.user2 WHERE friends.user1 = 1 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT user.id FROM user 
    INNER JOIN friends on user.id = friends.user1 WHERE friends.user2 = 1
)
```

**UPDATE:** With a bunch of new knowledge I have been able to get a solid SQL statment for my live feed that is 0.0009 seconds! Here it is for anyone who is interested.

```
SELECT stride.id AS link, sourceUser.userName, sourceUser.displayName, recipientUser.fName AS recipient, sourceUser.currentDefault, stride.content, stride.timestamp,

CASE WHEN (recipientId = sourceUserId) THEN "personalStride" ELSE "friendStride" END AS notType
FROM stride

INNER JOIN user AS sourceUser ON sourceUser.id = stride.sourceUserId
INNER JOIN user AS recipientUser ON recipientUser.id = stride.recipientId

WHERE sourceUserId = ANY
(
    SELECT CASE WHEN user1 = 1 
    THEN user2 ELSE user1 END AS sourceUserId
    FROM friends
    WHERE user1 = 1 OR user2 = 1
) 
AND recipientId = ANY
(
    SELECT CASE WHEN user1 = 1 
    THEN user2 ELSE user1 END AS sourceUserId
    FROM friends
    WHERE user1 = 1 OR user2 = 1
)
ORDER BY timestamp desc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need an union:

```
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN f.user1=u.id 
        THEN f.user2 
        ELSE f.user1 
    END AS f_id 
FROM user 
   JOIN friends AS f 
        ON f.user1=u.id OR f.user2=u.id
WHERE u.id = 1
```

Actually you don't need to join with user either (assuming of course that every id in friends table has a match in users table), I just added it so we can have nice "u.id" instead of magic number.

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN f.user1=2 
        THEN f.user2 
        ELSE f.user1 
    END AS f_id 
FROM friends AS f 
WHERE f.user1=2 OR f.user2=2
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/afb4d/8

**EDIT:**
As for the other query the matter is a bit more complicated I ended up with such a query:

```
SELECT s.id,s.sourceUserId,s.recipientId
FROM STRIDE as s 
    JOIN  friends AS f 
        ON 
          (
            ((s.sourceUserId=f.user1 OR s.recipientId=f.user1) AND f.user2=1) OR
            ((s.sourceUserId=f.user2  OR s.recipientId=f.user2)AND f.user1=1)
          )
GROUP BY s.id,s.sourceUserId,s.recipientId
HAVING COUNT(*)=2 OR s.sourceUserId=s.recipientId;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/83363/1
We select the row if source or recipient is the friend of our user and the we sum it up, if the row showed up twice it means both source and recipient are the friends. We also choose those where source=recipient as they will only show up once.

Subqueries are useful but they can be avoided unless you need two diffrent aggregates and usualy avoiding them will be much faster.

Comment: O boy. that looks like a foreign language to me. I need to read about what a case is now

Comment: What's going on here - then f.user2 else f.user1 - I understand the when part but what are the next two lines saying?

Comment: @gmustudent it tells which field to use if user1 is our user then show user2 else show user1

Comment: Never mind I get it! Thanks for forcing me to learn something new

Comment: Wow this case stuff is really speeding things up for me! Thank you so much! Now I'm case happy and using it all over and the times are dropping!

Comment: @TNK sorry for accidentaly overwriting your suggestion, I hope I fixed it.